# Фиксация меню при скроле как в ВК

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать меню как тут https://vk.com/dev/manuals
Получается я создал событие скрола для блока меню, он скролит как надо, но возвращается в исходное положение только тогда когда высота скрола меньше 1000px (так написано в условии, потому что не знаю правильно реализации), в общем нужно сделать так, что бы в любой части страницы при скроле вверх, блок меню тоже прокручивался.

Пробовал реализовать через position:sticky; но там безрезультатно, потому что меню начинает скролится только тогда, когда пользователь проскролит всю страницу

```
let leftNav = document.querySelector('.api-nav');
let menuScroll = (evt) => {
    if(document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1190) {
        leftNav.style.top = -scrollY + "px";
    
        if (scrollY > 1000){
            leftNav.style.top = -1000 + "px";
        }
    } 
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', menuScroll)
```

Comment: в ВК два меню фиксируются, боковое меню и горизонтальное, какое интересует?

Answer (score 0):

На контейнер с меню
position: fixed;